# Which (of the two below) approach of programming in actionscript is better/preferrable/performs better

Tags: actionscript-3, coding-style, standards

I have below piece of code in my actionscript file (defined in a function)

```
var cmbSyncItems:Object = new Object();
cmbSyncItems = {tooltip:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].tooltip, option1label:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].option1[0].label, option1data:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].option1[0].data, option2label:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].option2[0].label, option2data:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].option2[0].data};
cmbSync = new ObjectProxy(cmbSyncItems);

var btnFeedbackItems:Object = new Object();
btnFeedbackItems = {tooltip:xmlContent.messages.btnfeedback[0].tooltip, label:xmlContent.messages.btnfeedback[0].label};
btnFeedback = new ObjectProxy(btnFeedbackItems);
```

Below is the rewritten code utilizing the same 'items' object over and over again.

```
var items:Object = new Object();
items = {tooltip:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].tooltip, option1label:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].option1[0].label, option1data:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].option1[0].data, option2label:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].option2[0].label, option2data:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].option2[0].data};
cmbSync = new ObjectProxy(items);

items = new Object();
items = {tooltip:xmlContent.messages.btnfeedback[0].tooltip, label:xmlContent.messages.btnfeedback[0].label};
btnFeedback = new ObjectProxy(items);
```

The items Object will be repeated many times (more than hundreds) in the same file.

**Which method of coding is better (First block or second block) ?**

**Will it be okay if i take on the 'second'. Does using the first approach makes any difference (in terms of memory consumption)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'd rather suggest a third option:

```
cmbSync = new ObjectProxy( { tooltip:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].tooltip, 
                             option1label:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].option1[0].label, 
                             option1data:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].option1[0].data, 
                             option2label:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].option2[0].label, 
                             option2data:xmlContent.messages.cmbsync[0].option2[0].data } );
btnFeedback = new ObjectProxy( { tooltip:xmlContent.messages.btnfeedback[0].tooltip, 
                                 label:xmlContent.messages.btnfeedback[0].label } );
```

**upd**
the first approach doesn't seem to be much more memory hungry if all that objects are declared as local variables, but all that declarations are imho really needless

Comment: :) very nice. Your answer is a wonderful solution. No need to have extra variables :) Thanks